# Console Window closes

Tags: powershell, console, cmd

I have a application with arguments that I do not have source code for that I am trying run from Powershell. 
I can get it to run but it closes quickly and nothing happens.  I assume it it erroring because the file path I have is bogus.  How do I keep it open to see the error?

```
$*folder= ''
$title = "Organization"
$message = "Which Organization are you source controlling?"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Donaldson", "Donaldson"

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&US", "US."

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)

$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

switch ($result)
    {
        0 {$args = $action -and  "/zipfile:`"\\nasprod\prod$\dciprod\mscrm\customizations\Release\Global.zip`" /folder:`"C:\Users\mchaffee\Documents\Code\CRM\Global`"" }
        1 {$args = $action -and "/zipfile:`"\\nasprod\prod$\dciprod\mscrm\customizations\Release\US.zip`" /folder:`"C:\Users\mchaffee\Documents\Code\CRM\US`"" }
    }

Start-Process  "C:\Users\mchaffee\Documents\sdk\bin\solutionpackager.exe" $args*
```

Comment: Try running the powershell script from the powershell console or Powershell ISE.

Comment: if " I do not have source code for" means "I don't know the exact syntax", this may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out this help about start-process - http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849848.aspx. It has -wait switch.  Try it if that works out for you.

```
PS C:\> start-process notepad -wait
```